# How can I get rid of this whitespace around my h2 tag?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<h2>Hello world</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mekaron/w50mz2n3/

margin and padding are set to 0. why doesnt the text fit the border?
using javascript is an option here, but I have no idea where to start.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to make your h2 an inline element. Add `display: inline;` to your CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w50mz2n3/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Looking at your JSFiddle, you still have the weird whitespace.

Comment: If you're referring to the vertical whitespace, there's not much you'll be able to do about that.

Answer (score 1):

Play around with the l  line-height property.

```
.css{
 line-height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this sort of appears to do the trick. Any Idea why there is whitespace in the first place?

Comment: Just the default behavior of the h tag. No different then list being indented, paragraphs having space between them etc.

Comment: @user1189404 Because some characters that you haven't used will take that space. Keep this in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/w50mz2n3/3/

Comment: well, not really. List indenting and paragraph spaceing is just a mix of margins and padding. This has whitespace even without margins or padding

Comment: @George ah that makes sense! Any way around that?

Comment: What do you mean by *any way around that*? That's how letters work.

Comment: @user1189404 ...And h tags, along with all other text have a default line height property..... That can be adjusted as requried.

Comment: Well it just seems weird to have no way to actually fit a box around a h2 text without any whitespace.

Comment: it's like this for all text elements.

Comment: hm I guess that works... and then just hack around with javascript to detect some of the larger characters and ajust line height accordingly. Still not really pretty.

Comment: What is it that your are trying to do?

Comment: @Mark im trying to place a few lines of h2 text (h2 tag optional) underneath eachother, with the tops and bottoms touching without any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `display: inline`. It would be better still if you use a class as you can see in the snippet below :

```css
h2{
  display:inline;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

h2.simpleHeader {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<br />
<h2 class="simpleHeader">Hello world-class</h2>
```

Comment: The solution does not seems right , first thing there should not be 2 headers which is unneccesay , and second is even your code for the first header is not correct , hello world is coming in 2 lines, and it should come in one line .

Answer (score 0):

```
h2{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: #f00;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

try to add

```
display: block;
```

you could also try to play with all margins:

```
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
```